# Latex Beamer Command to make Image Slides

Tags: latex, beamer

I am using the following beamer command

```
\newcommand{\imgslide}[2]{
        {\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
        \includegraphics [width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{images/#1}} 
            \begin{frame}[plain]
                \txtonimg{#2}
            \end{frame}
        }
}
```

And I get errors repeatedly.

The same content when manually written works well.

And the command included within the above command is:

```
\newcommand{\txtonimg}[1]{
\begin{center}
 \fcolorbox{red}{black}{
 \textcolor{white}
 {#1}
 }
 \end{center}
 }
```

The error is:

```
]
! Too many }'s.
\endframe ->\egroup 
            \begingroup \def \@currenvir {frame}
l.107       \end{frame}
```

Everything seems good to me, on repeated testing.

Comment: This is going to sound silly, but have you experimented around with different whitespacing of your `\newcommand` ? I have had repeated problems with it simply because LaTeX wanted or didn't want something on a new line.

Comment: I created a minimal presentation with your commands and a sample image (in http://interfix.arane.us/stackoverflow/2633624/ if you want to try it on your machine) and LaTeX compiled it without complaint.

Comment: When do you get the error: when the macreos are being definied, or when they are invoked?  If the latter, what parameters are you passing to them?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. Turns out the error was something else, and I corrected it now. I was gonna delete the question, but since I think this question documents a nice command to create image slides, I decided to change the title and leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer uses a good deal of `\catcode`-related trickery, and it's likely that that is what's causing your problems.  Since I can't reproduce your error without a minimal example, I can only speculate (in general in the future if you want the most efficient help, provide a *complete* minimal example that exhibits the problem - in doing so you'll often narrow it down yourself, but at the least you ensure others can reproduce it faithfully).

Try adding the `fragile` option to the frame in your definition, as in

```
\begin{frame}[plain,fragile]
```

I'm not sure what the trade-offs are, but this causes the `frame` environment to behave more like a normal environment.